# Angular service not properly updating my $scope.data in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my voting app I'm just updating a simple `ng-repeat` with calls to my API to create, and delete polls. I had this working perfectly when all of my `$http` calls were in my controller but when I try to modularize my code with a service it doesn't update properly.

I don't fully understand promises, but I did some searches on here to see if that would work, but I didn't make any progress..

**Service:**

```
    /* global app */
app.factory("pollsService", ["$http", function($http){

    return {
        get: $http.get('api/polls').success(function(data) {return data;}),


    deletePoll: function(id, cb) {
        $http.delete('/api/polls/' + id)
            .success(function(results) {
                cb(results);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                throw err;
            });
    },

    createPoll: function(formData, cb) {
        $http.post('/api/polls', formData)
            .success(function(results) {
              cb(results);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                throw err;
            });
    }
    }

}]);
```

**Controller:**

```
/* global app */
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "pollsService", function($scope, pollsService){

$scope.formData = {};

pollsService.get
    .success(function(results){
        $scope.polls = results;
})
    .error(function(err){
        alert(err);
})

$scope.removePoll = function(id) {
    pollsService.deletePoll(id, function(results){
        $scope.polls = results;
    })
}   

$scope.createPoll = function() {
    pollsService.createPoll($scope.formData, function(results){
        $scope.polls = results;
        $scope.formData = {};
    })
}

}]);
```

My calls still work but I have to refresh the browser to get my updated data when I click on the newly created poll, or delete a poll.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: $scope.$apply() can invokes errors. It is beter to use $timeout(), this waits until the current digest cycle is finished

Comment: I tried $timeout and $apply, but still couldn't get it working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using service structure instead of factory. Also why don't you use $resource service? It could be solved easily with this approach:

```
/* global app */
angular.service("pollsService", function($resource){

    this.get = get;
    this.deletePoll = deletePoll;
    this.createPoll = createPoll;

    function get(){
     return $resource('api/polls', {}).query().$promise;
    }

    function deletePoll(params){
     return $resource.delete('/api/polls/:id', {id: params.id}).remove().$promise;
    }

    function createPoll(formData){
     return $resource.post('/api/polls', {}).save(formData).$promise
    }
})
```

---- CTRL

```
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "pollsService",    function($scope, pollsService){

  $scope.formData = {};


pollsService.get().then(function(data){
 $scope.polls = results;
}, function(error){

})

$scope.removePoll = function(id) {
   pollsService.deletePoll({id: id}).then(function(results){
    $scope.polls = results;
  }, function(error){
   // error here
  })
}   

$scope.createPoll = function() {
   pollsService.createPoll($scope.formData).then(function(data){
    $scope.polls = results;
    $scope.formData = {};
  }, function(error){

 });
 }

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll switch it over to the service structure using $resource. Definitely a better solution than what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

in order for `ng-repeat` to update the existing view with your new data - you will need to add `$scope.$apply();` after the data has been updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: $scope.$apply() can invokes errors. It is beter to use $timeout(), this waits until the current digest cycle is finished